# Write script to "Send file to device" in bluetooth

Tags: printing, applescript, automator

I'm relatively new to scripting and using application such as Automator. I would like to try create a script which detects when new images are added to a folder, prints them **twice** to a device (HP Sprocket) by using the "send file to device" option in Bluetooth, and then moves that image to another folder once the print has been sent (in queue) or completed.

I have used automator to create the transfer of the file, however I have no idea how to go about doing the printing aspect of this. Should I be using applescripts in automator? or another program?

Just for clarification regarding this, this is where the option sits when doing it manually.

[image]

The reason I am doing it this way and not just through a standard print is because the HP Sprocket doesn't work as a printer on any devices other than mobile, however you are able to send a file to the device this way with it still printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some bits of help:

To detect when files arrive in a folder, you need to Google *"Applescript folder actions"*.

I did something similar to what you are trying and used a folder in Dropbox which allows me to print from a smartphone by dropping files into Dropbox.... neat!

---

I used a POGO printer in my case, here is the `bash` code with embedded Applescript at the end:

```
################################################################################
# POGOprint
# Send image supplied as parameter to Polaroid POGO printer using Bluetooth
# File Exchange
#
# Mark Setchell
################################################################################

# User editable parameters - get address by clicking Bluetooth icon at top-right
# of the Mac screen and looking for the POGO

# Install ImageMagick using "homebrew", with:
# brew install imagemagick

pogo_address="00-04-48-13-9f-64"
tmp="/tmp/POGO.jpg"

# Get width and height of image using ImageMagick
read w h < <(convert "$1" -format "%w %h" info: )
if [ $w -gt $h ]; then
   # Landscape format - wider than tall
   convert "$1" -resize 900x600 $tmp
else
   # Portrait format - taller than wide
   convert "$1" -resize 600x900 $tmp
fi

osascript<<EOF
with timeout of 60 seconds
   tell application "Bluetooth File Exchange"
      send file "$tmp" as string to device "$pogo_address"
   end tell
end timeout
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I've gotten my head around the code and have almost got this working, however I'm struggling with how I can connect the "tmp" to the file which is added to the folder so I can print that image and then move it. How would I go about completing this part of the task?

Comment: See here for how to get the names of items added to a folder https://stackoverflow.com/a/36914030/2836621 For your application you don't need the `tmp` - I only did that because I wanted to resize the image before passing it to my printer. You can pass directly the filename you receive from `on adding folder items ...`

Comment: Try clicking `edit` under your question and pasting in your code, and I (and hopefully some others) will see if we can see any problems.

Comment: Never mind, I fixed this issue. It's working great now, only thing I would like to do is add a queue if possible. Because it can't send multiple files to transfer at a time, so would it be possible to create a make shift queue which waits for it to complete. But, I'll make another question addressing that! Thank you for your help.